# Querying DynamoDB in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb, sinatra-activerecord

In my app I create the following **model**:

```
class User
   include Dynamoid::Document
   # fields
   field :user_id, type: Integer
   field :name, type: String
   field :age, type: Integer
end
```

Then in my route:

```
# try search
get '/user/:user_name' do
    user = User.where(name: params[:user_name])
    if user
        json success: true, user: user
    else
        json success: false, message: 'User does not exist'
    end
end
```

But I am getting this: `2016-06-14 16:43:14 - NoMethodError - undefined method 'match' for nil:NilClass:`

What I am doing wrong? I want to use ActiveRecords

Adding more details:

> /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:67:in `block in partition_matching_region'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:66:in`each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:66:in `find'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:66:in`partition_matching_region'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:55:in `get_partition'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:26:in`endpoint_for'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:10:in `resolve'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/endpoint_provider.rb:80:in`resolve'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/regional_endpoint.rb:24:in `block in <class:RegionalEndpoint>'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:64:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:64:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:199:in`block in resolve_defaults'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:57:in`each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:198:in `resolve_defaults'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:194:in`value_at'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:183:in `block in resolve'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb:263:in`each_key'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb:263:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:183:in`resolve'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:171:in `apply_defaults'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:144:in`build!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:68:in `build_config'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:19:in`initialize'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.7/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:105:in `new'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/adapter_plugin/aws_sdk_v2.rb:15:in`connect!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:31:in `adapter'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:124:in`block in scan'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:53:in `benchmark'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/adapter.rb:124:in`scan'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:142:in `block in records_via_scan'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:115:in`each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:115:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:115:in`to_a'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:115:in `Array'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:115:in`records'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/criteria/chain.rb:95:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:128:in`to_a'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:128:in `as_json'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in`block in as_json'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in`map'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159:in `as_json'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:35:in`encode'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:22:in `encode'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:37:in`to_json_with_active_support_encoder'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:19:in `dump'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:25:in`dump'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.2/lib/multi_json.rb:136:in `dump'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/json.rb:113:in`block in resolve_encoder_action'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/json.rb:112:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/json.rb:112:in`resolve_encoder_action'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-contrib-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/json.rb:98:in `json'
>       /home/ll/fx-service/app/routes/users.rb:196:in`block in '
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1610:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1610:in`block in compile!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:974:in `[]'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:974:in`block (3 levels) in route!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:993:in `route_eval'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:974:in`block (2 levels) in route!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1014:in `block in process_route'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1012:in`catch'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1012:in `process_route'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in`block in route!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:971:in `each'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:971:in`route!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1084:in `block in dispatch!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in`block in invoke'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `catch'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in`invoke'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1081:in `dispatch!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:906:in`block in call!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `block in invoke'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in`catch'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1066:in `invoke'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:906:in`call!'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:894:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:211:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:181:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2021:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in`_call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:218:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in `call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in`catch'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in`process'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in`run_machine'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in`start'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in`run'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in`start'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rackup:23:in`load'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rackup:23:in `<top (required)>'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:88:in`debug_load'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:88:in `debug_program'
>       /home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/bin/rdebug-ide:130:in`'
>       -e:1:in `load'
>       -e:1:in`'

Comment: Can you show more error trace?

Comment: Are you using Sinatra or rails? Your title says one but your code seems to say the other.

Comment: You were right! I am using Sinatra

Answer (score 1):

The error in the stack trace seems to imply the AWS region is nil.  Did you configure the Aws library per the documentation here:

https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid

For example:

```
Aws.config.update({
    region: 'us-west-2',
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('REPLACE_WITH_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'REPLACE_WITH_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
  })
```

If so, can you post the code for your Dynamoid.configure call and Aws.config.update calls.

Comment: checking this @Phillipe Green

Comment: It is configured. If I do 
`TABLES['currencies'].scan.itemsTABLES['users'].scan.items` 

I am able to see the elements of the data baseIt is configured. If I do 
`TABLES['currencies'].scan.itemsTABLES['users'].scan.items` 

I am able to see the elements of the data base. 

Now in the model I was trying to create and index just below the fields:

`index :name`

but I am getting:

`/home/jcastelli/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/dynamoid-1.1.0/lib/dynamoid/finders.rb:128:in `method_missing': undefined method `index' for User:Class (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Defining indexes in this way was removed:

https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid/pull/17/commits/9dbed97f590b36546d34abeecf20bb333f5c5144

https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid/pull/17

Comment: You can define what your primary key is using the "table" function:
https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid#table

Secondary indexes can be defined per this example:
https://github.com/Dynamoid/Dynamoid/blob/master/spec/app/models/post.rb